# Extjs loading local JSON Object in to grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4, store

I am new to Ext JS and trying various options on Grid. I have created a grid and added it to panel(Ext.panel.Panel). The grid is getting displayed with empty data(I have not added proxy to it). On occurrence of some event I construct a JSON Object and trigger `loadData` on grid.

Following is my code snippet.

```js
Ext.define('AM.view.grid.Details', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.details',
    title: 'Widget Data',

    store: {
        autolaod: true,
        fields: [{
            name: 'widgetid',
            mapping: 'widget_id',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'widgetname',
            mapping: 'widget_name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'widgetnotes',
            mapping: 'widget_notes',
            type: 'String'
        }],
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    width: 620,
    height: 400,

    forceFit: true,
    columns: [{
        header: 'id',
        dataIndex: 'widgetid',
        hidden: true
    }, {
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'widgetname',
        width: 150
    }, {
        header: 'Note',
        dataIndex: 'widgetnotes',
        width: 150
    }],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

I have a function which is a callback function of another widget. When an event occurs this function getTriggered.

```js
function someFunction(grid) {
    var jsonData = formGridData();
    grid.store.loadData(jsonData);
}
```

Please assume that grid is created and I have function formGridData() which converts the formed String to JSON Object and returns.

So when I run the app, If the jsonData is of length 5 then 5 empty rows appear in the grid.

Following is the JSONData

```js
[{
    'widget_id':    'widget-1',
    'widget_name':  'gridpanel',
    'widget_notes': 'This is used to handle..'
}, {
    'widget_id':    'widget-2',
    'widget_name':  'combo',
    'widget_note':  'This is used to handle..'
}, {
    'widget_id':    'widget-3',
    'widget_name':  'panel',
    'widget_note':  'This is used to handle..'
}]
```

Is there anything wrong in what I am doing?

Thanks,
Phani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataIndexes on the grid are wrong.

```js
columns: [{
    header: 'id',
    dataIndex: 'widget_id', //was widgetid
    hidden: true
}, {
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'widget_name', //was widgetname
    width: 150
}, {
    header: 'Note',
    dataIndex: 'widget_notes',  //was widgetnotes
    width: 150
}]
```

What is happening is it is seeing the right amount of rows, but since the json you have as an example is named widget_* and note widget*, it thinks they are something else, and thus can not show them in the grid as appropriate

Comment: I have the dataIndexes right, I mean like the way you have it in the Answer.

Comment: Maybe my answer wasnt clear, I've revised it. If it was clear, then your question's json was wrong.

Comment: Ooops I have not seen your comments it indeed worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i didn't noticed that

So it seems your dataIndex is invalid

http://jsfiddle.net/ssxenon01/WpZMU/8/

Comment: jsonData is already in decoded format. jsonData is not a string but an JSON object

Comment: Thanks Xenon for your wonderful example. It did made my task easier. Thank you very much